# How to add additional profile to the aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I try to learn AWS and try to add profiles to the instance.
I created a Windows ec2 instance and two users (reader and writer), I use `awscli` for configure:

`aws configure`

After command execution I entered **reader** credentials.
After that two files were created in the `C:\users\Administrator\.aws` folder (**config** and **credentials**)
File **credentials** contains `default` profile, but I need to add two additional profiles to the server. In the final, **credentials** file should looks in the following way:

[image]

As I understood, I need to set Admin credentials for the command `aws configure`, but **how can I add two other profiles?**

Comment: If those are real AWS credentials then you should immediately [rotate and deactivate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_RotateAccessKey) the access keys.

Comment: Generally speaking, you are using the wrong solution to provide AWS credentials to your EC2 instance. Instead of hard-coded IAM user credentials, you should assign an appropriate IAM role to the EC2 instance. If the instance really needs multiple credentials, then the IAM role that it was launched with should be permitted to assume additional IAM roles, that themselves provide the needed permissions.

Comment: @jarmod A lot of thanks. Actually, I just follow the tutorial, I hope, in the future I'll get acquainted with the way that you mentioned.  *credentials aren't real, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your credentials file looks correct.  You can add as many profiles as you need.  Then when invoking a cli command you need to specify which profile you are using.  Ex.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile writer
```

Full details at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

So to add a new profile, you could add one named "admin" that  uses the access key/secret for the user with admin permission.

[image]